# Android: Increase responsiveness of phone screen?

Tags: android, touch, screen, multi-touch

Is there a way to increase responsiveness of a device for a particular application? Specifically, right now my touch events are definitely triggering, but they are delayed by a fraction of a second. Since my application is a music/rhythm app, any delay is very bad. I was just wondering, if there was anything I can do in the Manifest that would increase responsiveness. Or perhaps some suggestions for making the code work faster? I have to create multiple threads in the app as well to handle multitouch, perhaps there is  an efficient way of doing that?

Best,
Aneem

EDIT:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getAction()==ev.ACTION_DOWN||ev.getActionMasked()==ev.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN){                   
        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        int streamVolume = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        PointF[] touchPoints = new PointF[ev.getPointerCount()];
        for(int i = 0; i < ev.getPointerCount(); i++){
            touchPoints[i] = new PointF(ev.getX(i),ev.getY(i));
        }
        for(final PointF point : touchPoints){
            x = ev.getX(ev.getActionIndex());
            y = ev.getY(ev.getActionIndex());
            int ptx = (int) (x - x%widthIncrement);
            int pty = (int) (y - y%heightIncrement);
            playSound(pointMap.get(new Point(ptx,pty)));
        }
        return true;
    }
    return true;
}

public void playSound(int sound){
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int streamVolume = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    database.play(sound, streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would need multiple threads to handle multitouch. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: So my app is basically a drum instrument, I divide the screen into multiple regions, with each region having a unique sound. I want to because to hear three sounds at once if I press down on three regions at the same time. Instead of doing it iteratively, I figured using threads would do the trick, and it works. Perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your UI is sluggish, you are doing too much work in response to UI events. If you have to do anything non-trivial (load a sound file, etc.) in response to a UI event, then you should package that work into an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or other kind of worker thread. The UI response method should then just fire up the thread to do the heavy work, update the UI, and return.

The article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) has more details about how to do all this.

Comment: Well, I actually load all the sounds into a SoundPool during the "onMeasure" method which I think is run when the view is constructed. I then hash points to sounds in the SoundPool, so that when a touch event occurs, I use the coordinates to retrieve the sound from a hashmap. Do you think it would help if used I AsyncTask for retrieving sounds from the hashmap? (I thought getting from a hashmap was already optimized)

Comment: @Aneem - It sounds like you are doing things the right way. You're right that retrieving from a hashmap is fast enough to be done on the UI thread. The question now is whether it's your code or some lag in SoundPool that is the culprit. As an experiment, can you arrange for something to pop up in the UI immediately after calling `SoundPool.play` (or whatever you do to tell the system to play a sound)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I did the image test, and it seems that the image is much more responsive than the sound. I think at the end of the day, it might just be that the sound is slower on the device, but just in case you are curious, I posted some of my code up in the original query.

Comment: @Aneem - Android, unfortunately, has known audio latency problems (see the infamous [issue 3434](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3434). Despite being 2.5 years old, it's still an open issue.

Comment: Ahh, thanks so much! Hopefully this issue gets resolved in the near future!

Comment: @Aneem - If you haven't done so already, be sure to star the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You should handle touch events on your UI thread where they are received. You do not need to use multiple threads to handle multiple touch points. Data about all active touch points will be contained in the single MotionEvent object you receive.

If you're having some timing issues you might find the event time values provided by MotionEvent useful. You can get the time of when the event occurred both for the most recent event expressed by the MotionEvent as well as any historical events that have been batched into it. You can compare the event time with the current time when you process the event, allowing you to check "back in time" to correctly determine if the event occurred on the rhythm you're looking for. (The current time in the scale used here can be obtained from [SystemClock.uptimeMillis()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#uptimeMillis%28%29).)

Relevant methods:
[MotionEvent#getEventTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getEventTime%28%29)
[MotionEvent#getHistoricalEventTime(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getHistoricalEventTime%28int%29)

As Ted Hopp notes, you should also try to move any heavyweight processing out of your UI thread. The faster you respond to UI events, the faster you will get to pending touch events in the queue.

Comment: "Data about all active touch points will be contained in the single MotionEvent object you receive." But how I will I be able to play all touchpoint sounds at the same time? Doesn't there have to be some kind of concurrency?

Comment: Also, I need the sounds to be played in real-time, doesn't checking back in time defeat the purpose of that? Sorry, I'm new to this!

Comment: You could begin playing the sounds in-progress with the same offset. As for mixing, you don't need to use threads to play multiple sounds at once. Some Android devices have very high audio latency (the time between issuing a play command and hearing the audio) - you may be experiencing this even if the touch events are being handled right on time.

Comment: Got rid of the thread stuff, it does work a little better now. I'm posting some code up so you can get an idea of how I written it so far. Could you give me a hint as to how I can incorporate the time-related methods such as getEventTime() ?